# IIS 7.5 Scripts-folder outside of Content-folder

Tags: iis-7.5, static-content

I have just setup my asp.net site with IIS and I've found a problem with my javascript-files. From my visual studio project the files are stored in /Scripts/. But when I have the scripts in /Scripts/ in IIS I can't reach them.

If I move my scripts to /Content/Scripts/ then it work fine!

I have compared the permissions on the folders in IIS and from what I can see it's identical. What do I need to configure to enable my (standard?) Scripts folder?

Comment: It turns out that all other static content from other folders can be reach for example images in /Images/. So I tried that renamed my Scripts folder to some random chars and it started working. So somewhere in the IIS "Scripts" must be blocked/reserved word or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem... after a few hours I found empirically that the http:// server/Scripts was busy by QlickView server... so you can try bind application at other port, and test is it work or not... or try to find which application process this path